# How to award bounty to someone else's question?

Tags: support, bounties

How can we award bounties to an answer on someone else's question?

Comment: See also [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) on the main Stack Exchange meta site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to first set a bounty to the corresponding question. As soon as the time limit is over you can award any of the answers with your bounty.